# Foursquare Explore API radius parameter not working

Tags: foursquare

When using the explore endpoint with near vs ll gives different results when you specify a radius.

When using ll, the radius works as expected.  But when the query uses near it seems like it ignores the radius parameter.

My queries (without the client id and secret):
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?near=Menlo%20Park%20California&radius=250&section=coffee&v=20130101

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?ll=37.45383,-122.18219&radius=250&section=coffee&v=20130101

The first one overrides the radius parameter and in the response it shows a "suggestedRadius":7924
The second one returns a "suggestedRadius":250 like expected.

Am I doing something wrong? Has anyone else seen this behavior?
Is there a way I can use the "near" parameter and a radius correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `radius` parameter has no effect when used with `near`. For example, this query [https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?near=Menlo%20Park%20California&**radius=10**&section=coffee&v=20130101](https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?near=Menlo%20Park%20California&radius=10&section=coffee&v=20130101) or running it without a `radius` parameter altogether still returns the same results as your original query.

If you want to achieve a similar effect, perhaps narrow down you `near` parameter by doing something such as supplying a zipcode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was pulling hair out too :) It would be nice if that were spelled out better in the doc, however. https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/explore